# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, data-binding

I can't figure out why does this error appear on calling the GetData() method when executing the second statement. where it produces the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).", Please Help!!!

```
public async void GetData()
{
    Serializer("data1.xml");
    dm = new DataModel() { View_Model = await Deserializer("data1.xml") };
}  

public async Task<List<ViewModel>> Deserializer(string FileName)
{
    var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(FileName);
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ViewModel>));
    var x = new ViewModel();
    List<ViewModel> vm = new List<ViewModel>();
    using (stream)
    {
        vm = (List<ViewModel>)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);

    }

    return vm;
}

public async void Serializer(string FileName)
{
    var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(FileName,CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ViewModel));

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ViewModel));

    var x = new ViewModel();

    x.D_model = new Dmodel[] { new Dmodel() { title="Google",uri= "http://www.englishmonarchs.co.uk/images/plantagenet/windsr_22.jpg" } };
    using (stream)
    {

        ser.Serialize(stream, x);
    }                    
}
```

Comment: Could you show the xml structure? Or did you check if the xml is well formated?

Comment: You serialize as `ViewModel` and deserialize as `List<ViewModel>`?

Comment: @grek40 I deserialize as `ViewModel` but I put the deserialized content in a list variable 'vm'

Comment: @Zippy yes I did check the xml.

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanShalaby Maybe I'm overlooking something, but `deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ViewModel>))` looks alot as if you expect the xml root to be a list element. You should use the same typeof expression for serializer and deserializer.